# jQuery settings for form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, settings

I'm building a basic jQuery form validator. The code below is just to validate the name. I have several functions to validate mail, password, credit card, date etc. I want the user to be able to easily edit the error messages and classes. Let's say the user want to change the name of the class "error" or "success". Now the user needs to search and replace everywhere in the code where it says "error" or "success".

Is there any way to use an array or object at the top of the code to edit the error messages for each if-statement, and apply the classes?

Something like what's shown here: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#accepting-options (but at the top of the code, outside the function). Or could I use the same method but type like this (outside the function, at the top of the file)?

```
var settings = $.extend({
  color: "#556b2f",
  errorClass: "error"
}, options );
```

I also want the user to be able to add ID's and classes directly to the form element and type "true" in the setting "required" so the form element will be required. Is there some good way to do this?

```
var name = $("[data-name]"); 
var nameMsg = $("#nameMsg");

name.on("blur", function() { $(this).validateName() });

$.fn.validateName = function() { 
  if(name.val().length < 5) { 
      name.removeClass("success") 
          .addClass("error"); 

      nameMsg.removeClass("success") 
             .addClass("error") 
             .text("Not that short, at least 5 characters.");

      return false; 
  } else { 
      name.removeClass("error") 
          .addClass("success"); 

      nameMsg.removeClass("error") 
             .addClass("success")
             .html("Correct");

      return true;
  }
}
```

**Solution**

```
var defaults = {
    errorClass: "error",
    successClass: "success",
    successMessage: "<i class='fa fa-check-circle'></i>",
    errorMessageName: "Not that short, at least 5 characters.",
};

var settings = $.extend({}, defaults);
```

Special *thanks* to Martin Adámek for his help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$.extend just creates new object merged with values from both arguments, you can use it to extend default options object with user given (anywhere you want).

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, is this what you want?

```
var defaults = { // maybe you do not need extend at all? 
  errorClass: "error",
  successClass: "success",
  messageError: "Not that short, at least 5 characters.",
  messageCorrect: "Correct"
};

var name = $("[data-name]"); 
var nameMsg = $("#nameMsg");

name.on("blur", function() { $(this).validateName() });

$.fn.validateName = function() { 
  var userOpts = {...}; // you can store it eg in data attribute on the element
  // extend options with user given values
  options = $.extend(defauts, userOpts);

  if(name.val().length < 5) { 
      name.removeClass(options.successClass) 
          .addClass(options.errorClass); 

      nameMsg.removeClass(options.successClass) 
             .addClass(options.errorClass) 
             .text(options.messageError);

      return false; 
  } else { 
      name.removeClass(options.errorClass) 
          .addClass(options.successClass); 

      nameMsg.removeClass(options.errorClass) 
             .addClass(options.successClass)
             .html(options.messageCorrect);

      return true;
  }
}
```

The user given options would be stored as a JSON string (to allow merging with default options), so you would need to call JSON.parse() on in first.

**EDIT:**

Example of options JSON object in data attribute:

HTML:

`<input type="text" data-options='{"messageCorrect": "Bingo! That is the right choice!", "errorClass": "my-error-class"}' ...>`

and then in `$.fn.validateName()` you will do simply:

`var userOpts = JSON.parse($(this).data('options'));`

Comment: So I can't pass it with: `var defaults = $.extend({}, options);` ?

Comment: That would be equal to just `var defaults = options;`

Comment: Maybe I'm just missing your point, could you provide fiddle with your problem?

Comment: I don't have any problem, just want to know how I can do as you described. Have a settings object and define the setting with options.messageCorrect, for example. I din't quite understand what you ment with "need to call JSON.parse() on in first".

Comment: I will add that to my answer then